# CoffeeScript VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, coffeescript, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to use CoffeeScript on VisualStudio Express 2013 for WEB and when i create the file and build the solution wasnt it suppose to create the js files on the folder?

I tried to click on "Show All Files" to see if the file was there but wasnt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two extensions for Visual tudio:

1. http://vswebessentials.com/features/coffeescript
   OR
2. Mindscape, a tool and component developer out of New Zealand, has a free extension for Visual Studio 2012 (as well as 2010 and 2013) called Web Workbench that enables editing of CoffeeScript files right inside Visual Studio (as well as Sass and Less files). Just create a new .coffee file, edit away and, when you click "Save," the accompanying JavaScript file is generated and saved as well. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/10/01/top-7-reasons-to-love-coffeescript.aspx